# React Error: Objects are not valid as a React child when push array to ListItem

Tags: json, react-native, listitem, native-base

I have try to push a json into ListItem but getting Objects are not valid error. I guess it to happened as my json structure supposed to be like this :

```
json: [{
firstName: "firstName1"
lastName: "lastname1"
education: {
elementary: "school_A"
highschool: "highschool_A"
}
},
{
firstName: "firstName2"
lastName: "lastName2"
education: {
elementary: "school_B"
highschool: "highschool_B"
}
}]
```

and this is how i've setup my code:

```
    //set state
       this.state = {
       jsonPush: [],
       jsonList: []
       }


       componentDidMount() {
       this._listAsync(null);
       }


   //mapping json objet into listitem               
    var jsonPush= this.state.jsonList
           for (let i = 0; i < jsonPush.length; i++) {
                lists.push(
                    <ListItem key={i} avatar>
                       <Body>
                        <Text>{jsonPush[i].firstname}</Text>
                        <Text>{jsonPush[i].lastName}</Text>
                        <Text>{jsonPush[i].education.elementary}</Text>
                        <Text>{jsonPush[i].education.highschool}</Text>
                       </Body>
                    </ListItem>

  //hit api      
 _listAsync = async () => {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("params1", "value1")
            data.append("params2", "value2")
            data.append("params3", "value3")
            console.log("DATA = ")
            let datas = {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            let url = 'apps/api/getjson/'
            _post(url, datas, true)
                .then((json) => {
                    console.log("RESULT= ")
                    console.log(json)
                    if (json) {
                        this.setState({ jsonList: json })
                    } else {
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        };
```

it return me with this error

```
type error: null is not an object (Evaluating jsonPush[i].education.elementary)
```

I change `jsonPush[i].education.elementary` into `jsonPush[i].education` in order make sure whether the object is null or not, then i get another error.

```
Objects are not valid as a React child react error (found: object with keys {elementary, highschool})
```

how to access `elementary` and `highschool` element inside `education` and push it into listitem ? The object is not null but yet i cant access them.

Thank you.

Comment: could you please organize the code in your answer? You just put some parts of the code, but if you add the full component or at least the methods, that would be better. It's really hard to understand where in your component `//mapping json objet into listitem` is

Comment: I've edited my code above, but is it necessary for me to put all my codes ? i think my snippet is enough since it state how i state the element, how i get the json, and how i map json to variable then push it into listitem.

Comment: Where does lists comes from when you do lists.push?

Comment: i get the list from backend service i invoke using `_ListAsync`. I got a json object and then looping it into a listitem.

Comment: Yes, i mean the part where you the for loop, why do you use lists.push? where does the variable lists come from

Comment: sorry my bad, i use list.push and looping it in `for` and mapping directly as `<text>` object in `<ListItem>`

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the objects to string and then push them